# Unexpected result while encoding labels pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have the below code for encoding the labels:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

train_sentiments = pd.Series(['neutral', 'positive', 'neutral', 'negative'])
y_train = np.asarray(pd.get_dummies(train_sentiments), dtype = np.int8)

print('"{}" is converted into {}'.format(train_sentiments[0], y_train[0]))
print('"{}" is converted into {}'.format(train_sentiments[1], y_train[1]))
print('"{}" is converted into {}'.format(train_sentiments[3], y_train[3]))
```

Result that I get for the above part is, for the labels the encoded value is same:

```
"neutral" is converted into [1 0 0]
"positive" is converted into [1 0 0]
"negative" is converted into [1 0 0]
```

How to know what is the encoded values for for each label?

Comment: It is of the type `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` Sample from the series looks like - `5530     negative
7017      neutral
10916    positive`

Comment: What if you don't convert with np.asarray and index like `y_train.iloc[0,:]` or check `y_train.head()`

Comment: try passing train_sentiments as a list, I was able to get the correct output using that

Comment: I have tested your code, and I get a different result, I get the correct output:
 
    "neutral" is converted into [0 1 0]
    "positive" is converted into [0 0 1]
    "negative" is converted into [1 0 0]

Comment: @HodossySzabolcs can you please share the code you used for test. Atleast I can compare with what I have.

Comment: I have edited your question to have the same code I executed, but only thing I added is `train_sentiments = pd.Series(['neutral', 'positive', 'neutral', 'negative'])` and the imports.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: "neutral" is converted into [0 1 0], "positive" is converted into [0 0 1], "negative" is converted into [1 0 0].